# Lost my python.exe in Pycharm with Anaconda3

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, exe, pythoninterpreter

Everything was working perfectly until today, when for some reason my `python.exe` file disappeared from the Project Interpreter in Pycharm.

It was located in `C:\users\my_name\Anaconda3\python.exe`, and for some reason I can't find it anywhere!

Yet, all the packages are here (in the site-packages folder), and only the `C:\users\my_name\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe` is available.

With the latest however, some packages I installed on top of those available in `Anaconda3` won't be recognized.

Therefore, how to get back the `python.exe` file?

Comment: are you able to run python from console? If so, try `which python` or `where python` (first - mac\linux second - windows)

Comment: 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: and C:\users\my_name\Anaconda3\ is in my environment variables...

Comment: Are you using a virtual env? also, did you check inside the bin folder under the anaconda folder?

Comment: Issue like this happened to me once after anaconda update about half a year ago. I manually copied `python.exe` from the most fresh python package (folder `pkgs` then folder like `python-3.6.8-h9f7ef89_7`). This helped me. Try this way. Wish you luck.

Comment: @Poolka Looks like this is working like this. Thanks a lot! Actually I remember having had a windows update in between... -_-
I let you write the answer should you want to earn some rewards ;)

Comment: The packages may have been renamed, python.exe to python.exe.c~ for example if something happened during a conda operation. Renaming the files can fix the issues too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer repeats the comment to the question.

I had the same issue once after Anaconda update - `python.exe` was missing. It was Anaconda 3 installed to `Program Files` folder by MS Visual Studio (Python 3.6 on Windows10 x64).

To solve the problem I manually copied `python.exe` file from the most fresh python package available (folder `pkgs` then folder like `python-3.6.8-h9f7ef89_7`).

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same issue and found out that Avast removed it because it thought it was a threat. I found it in Avast -> Protection -> Virus Chest. And from there, you have the option to restore it.

Comment: thanks, my avast also put python.exe in quarantine

Answer (score 0):

My Python.exe was missing today in my existing environment in anaconda, so I clone my environment with anaconda to recreate Python.exe and use it again in Spyder.